# Change init program location in linux

Tags: linux, kernel, sysvinit, root-filesystem

In the linux kernel I found the following lines in the `main.c` file:

```c
if (!try_to_run_init_process("/sbin/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/etc/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/init") ||
        !try_to_run_init_process("/bin/sh"))
        return 0;

    panic("No working init found.  Try passing init= option to kernel. "
          "See Linux Documentation/admin-guide/init.rst for guidance.");
```

I wonder how can I change the init program's path to something else, `system/init` for example.

Any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: "Try passing init= option to kernel."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.11/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html

```
    init=           [KNL]
                    Format: <full_path>
                    Run specified binary instead of /sbin/init as init
                    process.
```

`system/init` is not a valid path (misses the root slash), it must be something like `init=/system/init`

Comment: But as the value is "hard-coded" in the code, how it will affect that? And what about `inittab` file? How can change path for that?

Comment: The kernel runs **only** init, nothing else. `/etc/inittab` is hardcoded in SysVinit's `init`, other init systems, e.g. `systemd` don't use this file at all.

Comment: `But as the value is "hard-coded" in the code, how it will affect that?` See https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/init/main.c#L1460-L1466

Comment: Your question has already been answered. You can pass a kernel parameter to change the path to the unit command.